# How do I get default ComboBox behavior in a DataGridTemplate column?

Tags: xaml, uwp, telerik, telerik-grid

In my RadDataGrid, I have to use a DataGridTemplateColumn because the Itemssource of my combobox is a collection that is a property of the object represented by the grid row. I've got it working except for the fact that the combo box is always editable. In other words, the box and dropdown arrow are always visible. In the screen shot below, the first column is a DataGridComboBoxColumn. The second is a DataGridTemplateColumn. Neither column has been clicked. (Note the column headings are not in the shot.)

[image]

In a regular combobox column on a RadDataGrid the combo box is not visible unless you double click on the column. Until you click, the column just displays the selected item. In my columns, the box and dropdown arrow are always visible, before and after you click in or out of the column.

How can I change this to the typical behavior? I want the user to have to click in the column before the box and dropdown arrow become visible. Before that, the column just display the selected item.  Here is my code:

```
<tg:DataGridTemplateColumn  SizeMode="Auto">
    <tg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Width="220"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemCategory.Items, Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Products, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Products.Id, Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectedValuePath="Id"
                      DisplayMemberPath="ItemName">
            </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
    </tg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
    <tg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <TextBlock.Text = "Item Category"/>
    </tg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
</tg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about ` the box and dropdown arrow are always visible`. Could you show a screenshot?

Comment: I edited to add a screenshot of the columns. The first is a regular DataGridComboBox column. The second is the DataGridTemplate column. I am trying to get the behavior of the first column in the second column. In other words, I don't want the combo box to show up unless the column is clicked. In the screen shot, neither column has been clicked, but you can already see the combo box in the second column (the DataGridTemplate column). Thanks!

Comment: Check whether the RadDataGrid set to `UserEditMode="Cell"`.